# Converting PDF to "Image Only" through Javascript

Tags: javascript, adobe, acrobat

I have a user that requires that a filled and signed PDF be a single image. In the current steps, this is what is done:

```
1. PDF is filled.
2. PDF print dialogue is opened (File > Print).
3. "Advanced" button is clicked.
4. "Print as Image" is checked and applied.
5. PDF is printed to a new file.
6. Original file deleted and newly printed file is renamed to original file name.
```

What I'm trying to accomplish is a way to do all of this with a click of a button. There are some efficiencies to be gained. For example, it would be nice if the user could click a button to do all of this, allowing the PDF to be saved to the original file.

This seems like an easy enough process, but it is repeated hundred of times a day. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

In this situation, you can use a javascript library like `printjs`. I included the CDN so you can use it immediately. And THe script is just an example. You can create a button and add a click function. In the function uses `printJS()` and as a parameter, insert the images dynamically. You can also check the library's documentation.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/print-js/1.0.63/print.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/print-js/1.0.63/print.min.css">



// add in your javaScript
function myPrint(){
  printJS('myFile.pdf');
}
$('#printBtn').click(myPrint);
```

I have used jquery to make it shorter.